# Using a filtered list in a new function in haskell

Tags: list, function, haskell, recursion, composition

So i'm not too sure how to phrase this properly, but say I wanted to get the sum of all odd numbers in a list, do I have two functions (sumList and getOddNumbers) and combine them into sumOddList or is there a way to put these two together in a single function? If there isnt a better function, how exactly would I combine them into sumOddList?

```
getOddNumbers :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
getOddNumbers [] = []
getOddNumbers (x:xs)
    |odd x = x:getOddNumbers xs
    |otherwise = getOddNumbers xs

sumList :: [Integer] -> Integer
sumList list = case list of
   [] -> 0
   (x:xs) -> x + (sumList xs)
```

I also ask mainly because putting two diff functions together is something I struggled with before, when putting a colour and a shape using CodeWorld to output a shape of that colour.

Thank you

(Note: I've been using Haskell for just over 5 weeks now and I'm a total noob clearly)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Passing output as input to (another) function

Well what you basically want to do is *use* the *output* of the `getOddNumbers` as *input* for the `sumList` function, so we can define a `sumOddList` function as:

```
sumOddList :: [Integer] -> Integer
sumOddList l = sumList (getOddNumbers l)
```

Here `l` is the list we want to process, and the result is thus a function application on the result of `getOddNumbers l` (with `sumList` the function).

## Chaining functions: the `(.)` function

The above pattern is quite common: frequently we want to pass data first through a function `g`, and the result through a function `f`. Haskell has the [**`(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c`**](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=(.)) function to "chain" functions. We can thus chain `sumList` and `getOddNumbers` together like:

```
sumOddList :: [Integer] -> Integer
sumOddList = (.) sumList getOddNumbers
```

Notice that we no longer use an `l` parameter here. `sumOddList` is here defined as a "pipeline" where data is first passed to the `getOddNumbers`, and then is "post-processed" by the `sumList` function.

The `(.)` function can also be used as an infix operator:

```
sumOddList :: [Integer] -> Integer
sumOddList = sumList . getOddNumbers
```

Answer (score 3):

In the following are three equivalent ways to write the function `oddSum :: [Integer] -> Integer`:

```
oddSum xs = sumList (getOddNumbers xs)

oddSum xs = sumList $ getOddNumbers xs

oddSum = sumList . getOddNumbers
```

Btw, have a look at the `filter` and `sum` functions in the [Prelude](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html) with which you could replace `getOddNumbers` and `sumList` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

> or is there a way to put these two together in a single function ... `sumOddList`?

Yes there is.

Chaining functions by using one's output as the other's input works, under lazy evaluation especially, but leaves us reliant on the *fusion* to be performed by a compiler. Which after all is not guaranteed to happen (and often doesn't).

Instead, *what you said* :

```
mapping f cons x xs = cons (f x) xs

filtering p cons x xs = if (p x) then (cons x xs) else xs

transduce xf cons z xs = foldr (xf cons) z xs

sumOddList xs = transduce (filtering odd) (+) 0 xs
```

Thus,

```
> sumOddList [1..10]
25
> sum [1,3..10]
25
> transduce (mapping (+1) . filtering odd) (+) 0 [1..10]
35
> sum . filter odd . map (+1) $ [1..10]
35
> sum . map (+1) . filter odd $ [1..10]
30
> transduce (filtering odd . mapping (+1)) (+) 0 [1..10]
30
```

This works because folds fuse by composing their reducer functions' transformers (like the `mapping` and the `filtering` above which are transforming their reducer argument `cons`):

```
foldr (+) 0
   . foldr (\x r -> x+1 : r) []
       . foldr (\x r -> if odd x then x : r else r) [] 
         $ [1..10]
=
foldr (+) 0
   . foldr ((\cons x r -> cons (x+1) r) (:)) []
       . foldr ((\cons x r -> if odd x then cons x r else r) (:)) [] 
         $ [1..10]
=
     foldr ((\cons x r -> cons (x+1) r) (+)) 0
       . foldr ((\cons x r -> if odd x then cons x r else r) (:)) [] 
         $ [1..10]
=
         foldr ((\cons x r -> if odd x then cons x r else r) 
                  ((\cons x r -> cons (x+1) r)   (+))) 0 
         $ [1..10]
=
         foldr ( ( (\cons x r -> if odd x then cons x r else r) 
                 . (\cons x r -> cons (x+1) r) ) (+))  0 
         $ [1..10]
=
         foldr ( (filtering odd . mapping (+1))  (+))  0 
         $ [1..10]
=
         foldr (  filtering odd ( mapping (+1)   (+))) 0 
         $ [1..10]
=
         30
```

One `foldr` doing the work of the three. Fusion *explicitly* achieved, by composing the reducer functions after the `cons` operation has been abstracted from them, each such changed function becoming a `cons` transformer, thus, liable to be *composed* with other such `cons`-transforming functions.