# Haskell Linear Search (returning index)

Tags: haskell, linear-search

So, I want my function to return the index (the first if it appears multiple times in the list) of a given value. It appears to work only for an empty list or if the given element has the index 0. Could you let me know what I do wrong?

```
linsearch _ [] = -1
linsearch y (x:xs) = head [i | let j = length xs, i <- [0..j-1], y == x]
```

Thank you.

Comment: You seem to be starting to write a recursive algorithm but then use list notation for just the current case (`x`) and ignore the remainder of the list (`xs`).

Answer (score 5):

Returning `-1` to represent a failed search is something you do in a language with a bad type system. Also, there is no reason to find *all* the elements if you only care about the first one. Further, `head` will fail if the resulting list is empty.

```
linsearch :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Maybe Int
linsearch _ [] = Nothing
linsearch y (x:xs) | y == x = Just 0
                   | otherwise = fmap (+ 1) (linsearch y xs)
```

An empty list obviously fails: return `Nothing`. With a non-empty list, check if
the first element is the one you are looking for; if so, return `Just 0`. Otherwise, `y` may or may not be in `xs`; recurse to find out. You'll add 1 to that result to account for `xs` being the "shifted" version of the original list. You need to use `fmap` because you won't be adding 1 to some integer `y`; you'll be adding it to a "wrapped" value like `Just y`, or possibly `Nothing` if `y` really isn't in the list. Note

```
fmap (+1) Nothing == Nothing
fmap (+1) (Just 3) == Just 4
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your response. Returning those exact values is a contraint of my assignment. I understood your way of solving this problem, but unfortunately I can't take this way in solving it. A solution that I know for sure that works is creating a new list of indexes and zipping it to the existent one of values, but I am still trying to figure out how to write that :)

Comment: You can use the same approach; you just need to check the return value of the recursive call. If it is -1, return that. Otherwise, return that value + 1.

Comment: Or, just wrap the `Maybe` version: `maybe (-1) id . linsearch` returns -1 if `linsearch` returns `Nothing`, or extracts the wrapped `Int` from a `Just` response.

Answer (score 1):

*TL;DR: the solution is at the end of the post.*

You don't need the list decomposition pattern in your definition, just deal with the list as a whole through the list comprehension:

```
linsearch :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Int
linsearch _ [] = -1
linsearch y xs = head [i | let j = length xs, i <- [0..j-1],
                           -- y == x  -- x? what is that?
                           y == (xs!!i)]
```

Now `linsearch 3 [0..9]` returns `3`, as it should. But `linsearch 3 [0..]` doesn't return at all -- it is lost in trying to calculate the list's length, which isn't actually needed here at all! Moreover, ditching the length calculation makes us re-arrange the algorithm  from its currently *quadratic* form into the much better, *linear* one:

```
linsearch :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Int
linsearch _ [] = -1
linsearch y xs = head [i | (x,i) <- zip xs [0..], y == x]
```

`linsearch 3 [0..]` now successfully returns `3`, *as it should*.

`linsearch 3 [0,2..]` still diverges though (i.e. never returns), because Haskell doesn't know -- nor does it *want to* -- that there's no point searching on an ordered *increasing* list while past the very first element which is larger than the one we're searching for. That is so because `[a]` is the type of *lists*, not of *ordered* lists.

We could define such variant though too, as e.g.

```
linsearchOrdered :: Ord a => a -> [a] -> Int
linsearchOrdered y xs = linsearch y $ takeUntil (> y) xs

takeUntil :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
takeUntil p xs = foldr (\x r -> if not (p x) then x:r else [x]) [] xs
```

And sure enough, it is working now:

```
> linsearchOrdered 3 [0,2..]
*** Exception: Prelude.head: empty list

> takeUntil (> 3) [0,2..]
[0,2,4]
it :: (Ord a, Num a, Enum a) => [a]    

> linsearch 3 [0,2,4]
*** Exception: Prelude.head: empty list
```

wait, what? Where's the error coming from? It comes from your use of `head`: since there were no `3` found in `[0,2,4]`, you code calls `head []` which is an error.

Instead, we can use `take 1`, and convert its result to a `Maybe a` with a standard use of `listToMaybe`:

```
import Data.Maybe

linsearch :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> Maybe Int
linsearch y xs = listToMaybe $ take 1 [i | (x,i) <- zip xs [0..], y == x]
```

Ok, *now* it's working:

```
> linsearchOrdered 3 [0,2..]
Nothing    

> linsearchOrdered 4 [0,2..]
Just 2
```

Note the return type is different now. Instead of using a special value, we use a wrapping type to indicate the success (with `Just`) or failure (with `Nothing`):

```
data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a
```

If you really want *your* original design, we can code it as

```
linsearch y xs = head $ [i | (x,i) <- zip xs [0..], y == x] ++ [-1]
```

Haskell is *lazy* so `head` will (safely, now, with the `++ [-1]`) stop on the first matching element (if at all possible). There's almost no duplicated effort going to waste, both with using `head` and `takeUntil`.

Both are folds though. `zip` can be coded as a fold as well, so `linsearch` is a fold too. And [folds composition can be fused into one fold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52034032/using-a-filtered-list-in-a-new-function-in-haskell/52034637#52034637) by fusing the reducer functions, turning it all into an explicitly one-pass algorithm, if so desired.

Answer (score 1):

There is a function `elemIndex` in `Data.List` which does exactly what you want. Your function could be written as follows:

```
import Data.List
linsearch y xs = elemIndex y xs
```

`elemIndex` returns a `Maybe Int`. So calling `linsearch 5 []` yields `Nothing` while `linsearch 5 [3,4,5]` yields `Just 2`. Side note, the above implementation allows you to drop the `xs`: `linsearch y = elemIndex y` is valid. Now if you want to return only an `Int` we can "extract" the value from the `Maybe` using a `case` expression:

```
linsearch y xs = caseExtract $ elemIndex y xs
  where
    caseExtract m = case m of
                      Just a  -> a
                      Nothing -> -1
```

If ya wanna get really fancy, you could go "point-free" by dropping the `xs` and using composition`(.)` with `fromMaybe` from `Data.Maybe` :

```
import Data.List
import Data.Maybe
linsearch y = fromMaybe (-1) . elemIndex y
```

The benefit of using library functions like `elemIndex` is that they are safe, unlike `head` which will go boom if passed an empty list. Reference: [Haskell Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch20.html#x28-24400020.7) [LYAH Data.List](http://learnyouahaskell.com/modules#data-list) [reddit unsafe head](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/5n51u3/why_are_partial_functions_as_in_head_tail_bad/) [fromMaybe](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html)

Comment: `caseExtract = fromMaybe (-1)`. it is defined in `Data.Maybe`. :)

Comment: @WillNess  Good looks!